# Emulator for Tizen Studio requires old libpng12-0

Tags: tizen, libpng, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I am about to install the Tizen Studio, and I also need the Emulators for Wear and Device. But unfortunately it requires `libpng12-0` , whereas I have installed `libpng16-16` already..

How can I tell Tizen Installer, it already has the last recent ones.. ?

Comment: Did you follow instructions in this link ( https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tizen-studio/download/installing-tizen-studio?langredirect=1 )? Does your development PC meet all of this prerequisites ( https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tizen-studio/download/installing-tizen-studio/prerequisites )?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer a solution, where I can use the last recent libpng version 16. But unfortunately I can not.

I met all the prerequisites here : https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tizen-studio/download/installing-tizen-studio/prerequisites - in vain. As above it wont find libpng12.

I made a dirty workaround yet: I downloaded https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpng12-0 the deb package from here and installed it with `sudo dpkg -i libpng12*.deb`

EDIT: This solution leads to another mistake while synaptic updates repositories:

> The repository 'http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng
>   xenial Release' does not have a Release file.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Ralf Wickum is the correct one; downloading libpng12 and installing it with either the sudo command or just by double-clicking.
I also tried getting the libpng12*so files themselves, but that does not seem to work; the tizen installer checks for the presence of the *package*, not the library.

The repository issue has nothing to do with the workaround. This is a stray line that you have added to one of the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ or to /etc/apt/sources.list . Remove the line and run sudo apt update and everything should be ok.